# How to create a pandas dataframe of word tokens from existing dataframe column of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nltk

I have a pandas dataframe **df** of the form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ID':[1,2,3], \
'Strings':['Hello, how are you?', 'Nice to meet you!', 'My name is John.']})
```

I want to tokenize the *Strings* column and create a new data frame **new_df**:

```
Sentence    Word
   0        Hello
   0        ,
   0        how
   0        are
   0        you
   0        ?
   1        Nice
   1        to
   1        meet
   1        you
   1        .
   2        My
   2        name
   2        is
   2        John
   2        .
```

I know for tokenization I can possibly use [nltk.word_tokenize()](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) for evert string in **df**, but how do I get from that point to **new_df** in a manner that is efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `map` and `stack`:

```
import nltk
pd.DataFrame(df.Strings.map(nltk.word_tokenize).tolist(), index=df.ID).stack()
```

---

To clean up the index, use `reset_index`.

```
(pd.DataFrame(df.Strings.map(nltk.word_tokenize).tolist(), index=df.ID)
   .stack()
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   .reset_index(name='Word'))

    ID   Word
0    1  Hello
1    1      ,
2    1    how
3    1    are
4    1    you
5    1      ?
6    2   Nice
7    2     to
8    2   meet
9    2    you
10   2      !
11   3     My
12   3   name
13   3     is
14   3   John
15   3      .
```

Comment: Thanks a TON for sharing this great solution.

Answer (score 2):

After nltk the problem became [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/7964527)

```
df.Strings=df.Strings.map(nltk.word_tokenize).tolist()

unnesting(df,['Strings'])
Out[22]: 
  Strings  ID
0   Hello   1
0       ,   1
0     how   1
0     are   1
0     you   1
0       ?   1
1    Nice   2
1      to   2
1    meet   2
1     you   2
1       !   2
2      My   3
2    name   3
2      is   3
2    John   3
2       .   3
```